# c++, error: Invalid use of qualified-name

Tags: c++, class, static-members, static-variables

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class sample {
    public:
        static int x;
};

//int sample::x = 20;

int main() {
    sample s1;
    int sample::x = 30;
}
```

When i compile this program then got an error **Invalid use of qualified-name 'sample::x'**

I know that I am getting this error because of this statement **int sample::x = 30;** in main.

But i don not understand that why i can not define  **int sample::x = 30;** in main?

Comment: Why are you trying to initialize a static atributte of a class in main, instead of the .cpp of the class, or just after the class definition in theglobal scope of the .h?

Comment: @Manu343726  i am just trying to clear my concept!

Comment: There is no reason to angry, I just did a question because I didn't understand what are you trying to do

Comment: @Manu343726  hey! i am not angry...But if my words hurt you then sorry....
My problem is that Why i can not define static member in main or in any other function??
i know that if i will define it outside the function then it is okay.
But it is necessary to clear the concept :)

Comment: @aaronman okay sir
but today i got my answer..

Comment: @Dixit don't worry. So yuo know that it must be initialized in the global scope. But you ask for the technicall reason of that? I think that is could be because static atttributes are, as global variables, stored at the global space of the process. So it must be initialied as global variables.

Comment: @Manu343726 you sort of reversed it, global and static variables are considered to have _static storage duration_

Comment: @aaronman yes, thats what I mean. Sorry of my stupid-like english level

Comment: @Manu343726 Thanks a lot. Hmmm You are right
it is wrong to define in a function because of local scope.

Comment: you consider the question answered? Would I write an answer with the content of my comment (And the @aaronman point) and accept that as answer?

Comment: @Manu343726 what would make the question answered?

Comment: @aaronman he questioned about the technical reason, right? And is not that reason showed by our comments?

Comment: @Manu343726 there I've amended it

Comment: @RyanHaining  Okay sir got u 
i am new to stack exchange, Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the standard says:

> The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.

Also, the definition of static data member is in the scope of a class.
So,

```
int x = 100; //global variable

class StaticMemeberScope
{
   static int x; 
   static int y;
 };

int StaticMemeberScope::x =1;

int StaticMemeberScope::y = x + 1; // y =2 (StaticMemeberScope::x, not ::x)
```

Comment: @Manu343726 then how did it get a UV

Comment: @Manu343726 oh, I know why you UV'd, standards quote

Comment: @aaronman Yes. The answer quotes the standard, followed by a short and well-pointed example.

Comment: @Uchia for future SO answers, here is a good markdown cheatsheet: http://joedicastro.com/pages/markdown.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to allocate space for it in global namespace

```
#include<iostream>

class sample {
    public:
        static int x;
};

int sample::x = 20;

int main() {
    sample s1;
    sample::x = 30;
}
```

You can the n set it normally in main or any other method. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html) on the static keyword. I removed the using directive because it is bad practice to bring in the whole namespace, especially when you need none of it.

The reason that static vars need to be initialized is global scope is because both static and global vars have *static storage duration*

Comment: You shouldn't advise anyone to use `using namespace std;`. I would have removed this part from the copied sample.

Answer (score 1):

Static member are like global object can only be accessed through `sample::x`

You've to initialize them at global scope where class is defined.

So you can't initialize in `main`, that's a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a static variable within a function, but must do this outside any scope:
Try

```
int sample::x = 30;

int main() {
    sample s1;
}
```

instead.
You can do though:

```
int sample::x = 30;

int main() {
    sample s1;

    sample::x = 42; // Note the different syntax!
}
```